# Apply filter parameters per environment or is there something better?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm working with a React application in GPC, and I have multiple environments [uat|training|staging]. Due to the way GCP is setup each application has a specific application configuration.

Therefore, I want to filter over my GCP app.yaml file to apply environment specific values per my build process.  Is there something in NodeJS that allows me to do this?  When building my current project I used create-react-app to do the initial build.

At this time, I'm still researching if anyone has done this or if this is an Anti-pattern with NodeJS applications.  Not sure if anyone else has run into this problem.

Comment: Asking for a software recommendation is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @georgeawg I'm looking for a way to apply filters to a yaml file on per environment using NodeJs, does that seem to constitute a "software recommendation"?